# Need to push files to android data folder in android 14

Tags: adb, root-access, file-transfer, file-permissions

I use Fl Studio Mobile to make music on my phone, and I recently switched to a Pixel 8 and need to transfer all of my Fl Studio files to my new phone. It's all in the app's data folder, due to how apps work, and I was able to back up all my files, but I can't get them into the app data folder on my new phone.

I've tried using the system file manager, but it can't write or modify folders that were created by FLM. If I copy "My Samples" for instance, instead of merging with the existing "My Samples" folder, it just creates "My Samples(1)". Can't move it or delete the original.

I've also tried adb, but it doesn't have have permissions to push anything to the app data folder.

Is there no workaround? I know in Android 13 there were a few tricks you could use, but now none of those work. I also need to be able to do this in order to backup and restore my saves for games like Stardew Valley and Terraria, which are also stored in the app data folders.

I heard there's a trick using the tmp folder, and running the push command as the app itself, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right, or I also don't have permission to use run-as. Can't root because I financed the phone and I can't unlock the bootloader until I'm no longer in t-mobile's pocket.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice, even if it's "you're out of luck".

To clarify, I'm talking about the main app data folder, as in the folder called "data" where every app is stored at `/sdcard/android/data`. In this case the app data folder is called `com.imageline.FLM`

For ADB I've tried the push command, and I've tried using run-as to use the app's permissions to move the files from the tmp folder. Nothing works, because I don't have permission to write to the `Android/data` folder. There used to be workarounds on Android 13, that apps like Total Commander used, but those have all been fixed. Even the system file picker itself can't write any files to the `com.imageline.FLM` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I updated with more information. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I have never tried this myself, but considering this seems to be a one time thing -- why not use a PC? By my understanding you need quite a few workarounds to get this working from within the phone itself (especially on Android 14), but you can copy to and from the data folder if you simply connect it to a PC. So just copy your files to a PC, connect your new phone and copy them back into the desired folder.

Comment: @SSS Jesse wrote "I've also tried adb" which I think means he already tries to do it via PC.

Comment: Android 14 doesn't even allow ADB on a PC to access the Android/data/ folder. You can pull files from it but you can't write to it.

Comment: D:\>adb push "file.txt" "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pl.solidexplorer2"
file.txt: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 72.4 MB/s (6878683 bytes in 0.091s)

Comment: I just tried that adb push on my Pixel 7 with Android 14 and worked without issues. And I could see it in that folder which I can access inside Solid Explorer. Btw, when I was talking about PC I meant simply copying it using Windows Explorer (or whatever OS you have) and not ADB specifically.